# Why does IPython `%timeit` yield a slower time for an O(n) solution?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, ipython, big-o

I am studying orders of magnitude by comparing anagram algorithms provided at [interactivepython.org](http://interactivepython.org/).  I'm using IPython's `%timeit` magic to test these functions.  The solutions are as follows.  The first algorithm:

```
# Sort and Compare
def anagram_solution2(s1,s2):
    a_list1 = list(s1)
    a_list2 = list(s2)

    a_list1.sort()
    a_list2.sort()

    pos = 0
    matches = True

    while pos < len(s1) and matches:
        if a_list1[pos] == a_list2[pos]:
            pos = pos + 1
        else:
            matches = False
    return matches
```

The second alogorithm:

```
# Count and Compare
def anagram_solution4(s1, s2):
    c1 = [0] * 26
    c2 = [0] * 26

    for i in range(len(s1)):
        pos = ord(s1[i]) - ord('a')
        c1[pos] = c1[pos] + 1

    for i in range(len(s2)):
        pos = ord(s2[i]) - ord('a')
        c2[pos] = c2[pos] + 1

    j = 0
    still_ok = True
    while j < 26 and still_ok:
        if c1[j] == c2[j]:
            j = j + 1
        else:
            still_ok = False
    return still_ok
```

The *sort and compare* function (solution 2) is stated to be higher order, either an O(n^2) or O(nlogn) solution.  The *count and compare* function (solution 4) is stated to be an O(n) solution, so I expect a shorter time if tested with `%timeit`.  However, I get the following results:

```
%timeit anagram_solution2('conversationalists', 'conservationalists')
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 13 µs per loop

%timeit anagram_solution4('conversationalists', 'conservationalists')
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 21 µs per loop
```

Perhaps I am missing something fundamental, but why is the linear solution taking longer than the quadratic/log-linear solution?

**EDIT**

For completeness, I'm including a graph of [common Big-O functions](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/AlgorithmAnalysis/BigONotation.html).  There appears to be an intersection for log-liner and liner curves at lower "x" values.
[image]

Comment: try with large data, you cannot get  proper read using small amounts of data.  `s1 = s2 =  "zwvuxabcdefg"  * 1000` `anagram_solution2(s1,s2)`
`

Comment: You would probably need much bigger data size to see difference between linear and `n log n ` solution (it might be even impractically large input depending on constant factors).

Comment: Yeah.  I tried using longer words from the original anagram (' apple' , ' pleap'). I'm still surprised it's giving an unexpected answer.

Comment: They are a different order, but for small numbers the constants hidden by the asymptotic behavior are significant.

Comment: The difference is in 10's of microseconds.. That's not really any difference at all. At that scale it's hard to detect any difference because it could just be noise from OS scheduling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that O() notation refers to *only* the dominating term of the overall time equation.  For instance, O(n) may refer to a process that takes 1000*n + 7000 seconds; a competing O(n^2) process may be 0.5*n^2 + .10 seconds.  N has to be very large for the n^2 process to run in less time.

In this case, the O(n) algorithm goes through three individual n-length loops, with a couple of operations thrown in.  This will make it slower for small values of N.  I'll go run a couple of tests ...

---

I tried this with two letters, then one copy of the alphabet, then 30 copies:

```
length 2    O(n^2) 1.00135803223e-05    O(n) 1.50203704834e-05
length 26   O(n^2) 1.69277191162e-05    O(n) 2.59876251221e-05
length 780  O(n^2) 0.000540971755981    O(n) 0.00049901008606
```

In my environment, the O(n) algorithm doesn't catch up until maybe 500 characters, but it will be the faster algorithm from then on.

Comment: You are *very* correct.  Many times in my professional coding, I've implemented a trivial O(n^2) algorithm instead of a sophisticated O(n log n) algorithm -- such as a bubble sort instead of a merge sort.  The trivial one is easier to adapt or maintain, easy for new teammates to understand, and the time savings for small lists (we often work in the 10-100 range) were insignificant, if any.

Comment: Do remember to choose your favourite answer; it closes the question properly.  You have three good candidates from which to choose.

Comment: Thanks for the test results.  My tests show improvements around 1000 tokens.  Since 500-1000 words are impractical, is it safe to say a "better" O algorithm is not always the most practical one?

Answer (score 2):

`O[N]` and `O[N^2]` are about scaling, not about absolute time. For example, an `O[N]` algorithm might take 10 seconds for 10 points, 100 seconds for 100 points, 1000 seconds for 1000 points, etc.

An `O[N^2]` algorithm might take 10ms for 10 points, 1sec for 100 points, and 100sec for 1000 points, etc.

Notice here the `O[N^2]` algorithm is faster than the `O[N]` in the sense of how much clock time it takes, but that the scaling is different.

`O[N]` measures how time scales with increasing N, not the amount of time the algorithm takes.

Answer (score 2):

There's already 3 good answers, but I think this adds a slightly different perspective.

In general terms big notation really only states that **a lower order algorithm will be faster than a higher order algorithm *at some point***. Big O by itself gives absolutely no information as to when that point is. It could be `N=3` or `N=10^1000`.

That being said, for practical algorithms, it tends to happen before N=1 million or so and often before N exceeds 10,000 or so. In the case of smaller inputs (N < 10 or so) it's quite often the case that the simplest algorithm is the fastest regardless of the big O, as long the algorithm is realistic, unlike say [Bogosort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort).

An analogy can be driven with different means of transport. For increasing distances to travel, the most effective means, in turn, are: on foot - bicycle - car - train - airplane. Each one starts worse than the previous for smaller distances, but eventually starts outperforming it.

This leads to another conclusion: **simpler but "slower" algorithms have full rights to exist and be chosen over "faster" ones if your data size is in the segment where they are more effective.** It's another issue that you cannot possibly predict how large your data will ever be, especially if it's a software library. That's why the "latest and greatest" are typically chosen anyway or the code alternates between a few methods if the tradeoffs of choosing a single one are big enough.

Answer (score 1):

Constants!

The linear solution could be something like

```
t_linear = c0 + c1 * N
```

The other could be something like

```
t_square = d0 + d1 * N + d2 * N**2
```

Where the c's and d's are constants.

Lets set `c0 = 100, c1 = 1; d0 = 1, d1 = 0 and d2 = 1`

Then for small N, say `N = 4` we get t_linear = 104 and t_square = 17, i.e. `t_linear > t_square`

As N increases then t_square approaches then exceeds t_linear, i.e. for `N = 11` we get t_linear = 111 and t_square = 122, i.e. `t_linear < t_square`

I guess modern CPU architectures could also foul timings if cache limits are hit; Operating systems could be rigged to recognise benchmarks and favour one example over another; ...  **but Constants are the more likely reason.**